# Ubuntu16.04.5 - Fonts not rendering properly in Firefox

Tags: 16.04, firefox, fonts

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.5 just now! And it is great.
The issue is Mozilla Firefox is not rendering Fonts properly. Please check the screenshot to see what I mean.

Do I have to install any dependency plugins or extensions? Please do let me know how to resolve this.

I am not a very experienced Linux user.

[image]

Comment: You may want to install the `fonts-indic` package.

Comment: Hello @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks a lot for your help!, Firefox is rendering properly now...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to install the fonts-indic package.

*Answered by Gunnar Hjalmarsson*

Installing fonts-indic via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
```